# Dynamically adding static functions to class from other class

Tags: php, class, oop

I have the following class, `API`, that 'receives' functions from other classes (just `Pipelines`in this example), so API::getPipelines() returns Pipelines::getPipelines() and so on. The list of API functions will grow and this code will grow larger and larger was well, so I'm looking for a way to dyamically add these functions to the `API` class. For example: `register_methods_from(array('Pipelines', 'Blah'))`. What is the best way to do this?

```
class API
{

/**
 * The current API instance
 */
private static $_instance = null;

[...]

/**
 * Define API funcs
 */
public static function getPipelines() {
    return Pipelines::getPipelines();
}
public static function getPipeline($id) {
    return Pipelines::getPipeline($id);
}

// etc...
```

Comment: Use `__call` for example and check if method exists in Pipeline class, after that invoke it or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use PHP's magic method `__callStatic` for this:

```
class API
{
    static function __callStatic($name, $arguments)
    {
        if ( ! method_exists('Pipelines', $name))
        {
            return null; // Or throw error
        }

        return call_user_func_array('Pipelines::' . $name, $arguments);
    }
}
```

You can even make `Pipelines` dynamic here.

Also you may want to use autoloading instead, which allows you to return an instance of `Pipelines` when something like `$api = new API();` is used.

Hope it helps!

---

Sources:

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.callstatic
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.method-exists.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php